# Prism over maybe-existent list element

Tags: haskell, traversal, haskell-lens

today on "adventures in functional programming with lenses" our hero attempts to define a prism over a list element that may or may not exist.

It's a bit tricky to explain, so to avoid the X, Y problem I'll give the actual use-case in all its glory.

I'm writing a Text editor in Haskell called [Rasa](https://github.com/chrispenner/rasa), the whole idea is that it's extremely extensible, and that means most functionality is written as extensions. Since it's a core principle, extensions ALSO depend on other extensions, so I needed a way to store their state centrally such that all extensions depending on an extension could access its current 'extension state'. Of course the types of these states is not known to the core of the editor, so at the moment I'm storing a list of [Dynamic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) values. When the extension stores the state it converts to a Dynamic, then it can be extracted later via a prism like so:

```
data Store = Store
  { _event :: [Event]
  , _editor :: E.Editor
  , _extState :: [Dynamic]
  }

ext :: Typeable a => Traversal' Store a
ext = extState.traverse._Dynamic
```

So now `ext` is a polymorphic Traversal that essentially operates over only the Dynamics that 'match' the type in question (if you set to it it'll replace values of the same type, if you 'get' from it, it acts as a traversal over the Dynamics that match the type of the outbound value). If that seems like magic, it basically is...

BTW, I'd love to have exactly 1 copy of a given Extension's state object in the list at any time.

So getting and setting is actually working fine IFF there's already a value of the proper type in the list, **my question is how can I make a version of this Traversal such that if a value of the proper type is in the list that it will replace it (and getting works as expected), but that will ADD a value to the list if the traversal is SET to and there's NO matching element in the list.** I understand that Traversal's aren't supposed to change the number of elements that they're traversing, so perhaps this needs to be a prism or lens over the list itself?

I understand this is really confusing, so please ask clarifying questions :)

As for things I've taken a look at already, I was looking at [prefixed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Data-List-Lens.html#v:prefixed) and [_Cons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v:Cons) as possible ways to do this, but I'm just not quite sure how to wire it up. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely.

I could perhaps add a default value to the end of the traversal somehow, but I don't want to require Monoid or Default so I can't conjure up elements from nowhere (and I only want to do it when SETTING).

I'm also open to discussions about whether this is actually the proper way to store this state at all, but it's the most elegant of solutions I've found so far (though I know typecasting at run time is sub-optimal). I've looked into the Vault type, but passing keys around didn't really work well when I tried it (and I imagine it has similar type-casting performance issues).

Cheers! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the list of extensions is not proper solution for you. I would be added something like `_extState :: Map TypeRep Ext` where `data Ext = forall a. Ext a`. Then I would be added the lens:

```
ext :: forall a . Typeable a => Lens' Store (Maybe a)
ext = _extState . at (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy a)) . mapping coerce
  where
    coerce = iso (\(Ext x) -> unsafeCoerce x) Ext
```

This lens does like `at`. So you can simply get/set your extensions.

But there is one limitation, all extensions must be of different types.

Comment: Looks like this could work! Would you be able to explain the (Proxy :: Proxy a)? Does it create a TypeRep for the provided type?

Also, do I need `coerce` and Ext, or could I do a `Map TypeRep Dynamic`? or is using the Ext with existential quantification faster? (I suppose the unsafeCoerce is safe since I know which type is stored by the typeref). Just wondering why you made the choice to go with `Ext a`. I'll fiddle with this as soon as I have time and let you know if it fits!

Comment: P.S. I only wanted there to be one of each Extension type anyways, so that's actually a feature not a limitation :D

Comment: Yes, it does. It's new way to get TypeRep for something. It was added to base since 4.7.0.0. For doing with `(Proxy :: Proxy a)` you have to use `-XScopedTypeVariables`

Comment: Awesome! If this works out we have a winner! For future reference; as a beginner I find it very helpful to have required extensions listed in the answer (and perhaps explained if non-obvious). Even though GHC usually lets me know, it's a better experience for those less experienced :D

Comment: You can do with `Map TypeRep Dynamic` but it has overhead, because you known the type of value which you get from the map, but extraction from `Dynamic` will be checking it again.